# Xamarin Forms. Application running in the background for Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I just recently started learning Xamarin and faced such a challenge. I need that when minimizing, closing, and even when the user clears memory, my application starts and remains in the background all the time. I'm trying to create a service, but I don't fully understand how to implement everything. Is it even possible to implement this in Xamarin? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/

Comment: [Foreground Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services) is what you need , it keeps working even if the app is closed .